# Iterator range for console class that handles multiple buffers

Tags: c++, c++11

This question is a spiritual successor to [**Console class that handles multiple buffers**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63225/console-class-that-handles-multiple-buffers). I was mostly interested in implementing one of the suggestions of using an iterator range and fixing the interface for `Terminal`. That means most of the code will be absent. Also, while the code above is intended for a freestanding environment, mine is in a hosted one and uses the standard library. Stuff like `std::iterator` and `std::copy` are easy to implement, meaning that I can easily convert it once I start developing the full application.

Here's an example of improvements over the original code:

```
// Original

void Terminal::clrbuf(int buffer)
{
    for (int i = buffers[buffer].ybase * buffers[buffer].columns; 
             i <  (buffers[buffer].ybase + buffers[buffer].rows) 
                 * buffers[buffer].columns; ++i)
    {
        video_buffer[i] = make_vgaentry(' ', buffers[buffer].color);
    }
}

// Mine

void clear_buffer()
{
    for (auto& c : BufferRange{current_buffer()})
    {
        c = ' ';
    }
    current_buffer().xpos = 0;
    current_buffer().ypos = 0;
}

// Original


for (int i =   buffers[current_buffer].ybase
             * buffers[current_buffer].columns; 
         i <  (buffers[current_buffer].ybase + buffers[current_buffer].rows - 1) 
             * buffers[current_buffer].columns; i++)
{
    video_buffer[i] = video_buffer[i + buffers[current_buffer].columns];
}

 // Mine

auto range = BufferRange{*buffer};
auto start = range.begin();

// (buffer->ybase + Buffer::rows - 1) * Buffer::columns
auto end = range.end() - Buffer::columns;
for (auto it = start; it != end; ++it)
{
    *it = it[Buffer::columns];
}
```

My idea is to emphasize abstraction by hiding the details behind iterators while strengthening interopability with alogrithms. Example:

```
void puts(const char* s)
{
    std::copy(s, s + std::strlen(s),
        BufferWriteIterator{current_buffer()});
}
```

The issue is that `BufferWriteIterator` does all of the work (in adjusting the internals and scrolling). However, my goal was to make classes related to `Buffer` do as little work as possible and make it the responsibility of `Terminal` to do that. I'm not sure of a good solution however, because I don't want `BufferWriteIterator` to care about `Terminal` either (i.e, having it as a member variable). On the other hand, the code is designed to affect the current buffer and not other buffers, suggesting that the `Terminal` shouldn't be responsible for it either.

Is this a good approach?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

class Buffer
{
private:
    char buffer[1024];
public:
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    // What line the buffer starts at
    int ybase;

    constexpr static int columns = 80;

    // This is how many lines each buffer gets.
    constexpr static int rows = 12;

    int current_pos()
    {
        return xpos + (ybase + ypos) * columns;
    }

    char& operator[](int idx)
    {
        assert(idx >= 0 && idx < 1024);
        return buffer[idx];
    }
};

struct BufferRange
{
    Buffer& buffer;
    char* begin() { return &buffer[buffer.ybase * Buffer::columns]; }
    char* end()   { return &buffer[(buffer.ybase + Buffer::rows) * Buffer::columns]; }
};

class BufferWriteIterator
    : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
private:
    Buffer* buffer;
public:
    BufferWriteIterator()
        : buffer{nullptr}
    {}

    BufferWriteIterator(Buffer& b)
        : buffer{&b}
    {}

    BufferWriteIterator& operator=(char c)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            buffer->xpos = 0;
            buffer->ypos++;
        } else {
            (*buffer)[buffer->current_pos()] = c;
            buffer->xpos++;
        }

        if (buffer->xpos >= Buffer::columns)
        {
            buffer->xpos = 0;
            buffer->ypos++;
        }

        // Scroll
        if (buffer->ypos >= Buffer::rows) 
        {
            auto range = BufferRange{*buffer};
            auto start = range.begin();

            // (buffer->ybase + Buffer::rows - 1) * Buffer::columns
            auto end = range.end() - Buffer::columns;
            for (auto it = start; it != end; ++it)
            {
                *it = it[Buffer::columns];
            }

            start = end;
            end = range.end();
            for (auto it = start; it != end; ++it)
            {
                *it = ' ';
            }
            buffer->ypos = Buffer::rows - 1;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    BufferWriteIterator& operator*()     {return *this;}
    BufferWriteIterator& operator++()    {return *this;}
    BufferWriteIterator& operator++(int) {return *this;}    
};

class Terminal
{
private:
    Buffer buffers[2];
    int buffer_idx;

    Buffer& current_buffer()
    {
        return buffers[buffer_idx];
    }
public:
    Terminal()
        : buffers{}, buffer_idx{0}
    {
        buffers[0].ybase = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 1; i < sizeof(buffers); ++i)
        {
            // Add 1 since there will be a horizontal
            // separator every 12th row
            buffers[i].ybase = Buffer::rows * i + 1;
        }
    }

    void clear_buffer()
    {
        for (auto& c : BufferRange{current_buffer()})
        {
            c = ' ';
        }
        current_buffer().xpos = 0;
        current_buffer().ypos = 0;
    }

    void puts(const char* s)
    {
        std::copy(s, s + std::strlen(s),
            BufferWriteIterator{current_buffer()});
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```